# Concatenating NULL returns a value in T-SQL (CONCAT function)

Tags: t-sql, concatenation, string-concatenation

Why does this return `.` when col1 contains a blank value?

```
CONCAT(NULLIF([COL1],''),'.')
```

I have 3 columns that i need to concatenate with a `.` in between, sometimes the column contains a blank value. In that case the trailing `.` should not be concatenated. What functions do I use?

```
col1 col2 col3 
A     1    x
B     2
```

expected results:

```
A.1.X
B.2
```

test code:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(a varchar(100),b varchar(100),c varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'A','1','X' UNION
SELECT 'B','2','' UNION
SELECT 'C','','' UNION
SELECT '','1','X' UNION
SELECT 'B','','' UNION
SELECT 'C','',''

SELECT CONCAT ( Nullif(a,''),'.' + nullif(b,''), '.' + nullif(c,'')) AS Contact_Result FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Do you mean `[COL1]` contains an empty string or a `NULL`?

Comment: What would it look like if the middle or first column was blank?

Comment: same thing the . should not appear

Comment: @user1721546 you used my answer as your question, that is great lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*THIS IS AN ANSWER THAT COVERS ALL POSSIBILITIES*

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONCAT ('.' + NULLIF(a,''),'.' + NULLIF(b,''),'.' + NULLIF(c,'')),2,10000) AS Contact_Result FROM @tbl;
```

Complete test cases

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(a varchar(100),b varchar(100),c varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'a','','' UNION
SELECT 'a','b','' UNION
SELECT 'a','b','c' UNION
SELECT 'a','','c' UNION
SELECT '','b','c' UNION
SELECT '','b','' UNION
SELECT '','','c' UNION
SELECT '','','' 


SELECT SUBSTRING(CONCAT ('.' + NULLIF(a,''),'.' + NULLIF(b,''),'.' + NULLIF(c,'')),2,10000) AS Contact_Result FROM @tbl;
```

**Results**

```
c
b
b.c
a
a.c
a.b
a.b.c
```

Comment: Hugo Tereceros - with all due respect, you need to read all the solutions before making bold statements like, "THIS IS THE ONLY VALID ANSWER for this question that really COVERS ALL POSSIBILITIES." 

First, what I posted also covers all possibilities AND is the only solution that works without SQL Server 2012 (which is why I thought it was worth posting). Second, you posted two answers - are you suggesting that your other answer is wrong? If so why not correct or delete it?

Comment: Alan sorry for that I edited my answer, I did not want to hurt anybody

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) this way

```
SELECT CONCAT ( a,IIF((NULLIF(a,'')+NULLIF(b,'')) IS NULL,'','.'),b,IIF((NULLIF(b,'')+NULLIF(c,'')) IS NULL,'','.'), c) AS Contact_Result FROM @tbl;
```

Test code below

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(a varchar(100),b varchar(100),c varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'A','1','X' UNION
SELECT 'B','2',NULL UNION
SELECT 'C',NULL,NULL


SELECT CONCAT ( a,IIF((NULLIF(a,'')+NULLIF(b,'')) IS NULL,'','.'),b,IIF((NULLIF(b,'')+NULLIF(c,'')) IS NULL,'','.'), c) AS Contact_Result FROM @tbl;
```

Contact_Result

```
A.1.X 
B.2 
C
```

Another common use of this kind of concats is to **Concat a Full Name** in this case the . (dot) is replaced by a ' ' (space), it makes things easier because you can use *trim*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(a varchar(100),b varchar(100),c varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'FirtName','MiddleName','LastName' UNION
SELECT 'FistName','','LastName' UNION
SELECT '','','FullName'


SELECT LTRIM(CONCAT ( a,' ' + b,' ' + c)) AS Contact_Result FROM @tbl;
```

Result

```
FullName
FirtName MiddleName LastName
FistName  LastName
```

Comment: In your sample data you used `NULL` but I think he actually has `''`

Comment: CONCAT ( REPLACE([a],'',NULL),'.' + REPLACE([b],'',NULL), '.' + REPLACE ([c],'',NULL),'.' +REPLACE([d],'',NULL))

Comment: @user1721546 I added an **NULLIF blank** which acts exactly as your REPLACE, I think it does the trick

Comment: edited my question to show your suggestion couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go old school. I'm on my phone and can't test this.

<strike>ISNULL(NULLIF([COL1],'') + '.', '') +
    ISNULL(NULLIF([COL2],'') + '.', '') +
    ISNULL(NULLIF([COL3],''), '');</strike>

**---------------- EDIT ----------------**

Okay, this was not as easy on my phone as I thought. Here's my updated solution that works with SQL Server 2005+

```
-- sample data
declare @table table 
(
  id int identity, 
  col1 varchar(10), 
  col2 varchar(10),
  col3 varchar(10)
);

insert @table (col1, col2, col3) 
values ('a','b','c'), ('aa','bb',''), ('x','','z'), ('','p','pp'), 
       ('!!!','',''), ('','','fff'), ('','','');

-- My solution
select col1, col2, col3, concatinatedValue = 
  case when cv like '.%' then stuff(cv, 1, 1,'') else cv end
from @table
cross apply (values 
  (isnull(nullif([col1],''), '') +
   isnull('.'+nullif([col2],''), '') +
   isnull('.'+nullif([col3],''), ''))) v(cv);
```

**RETURNS**

```
cv        col1  col2  col3  concatinatedValue
--------- ----- ----- ----- -------------------
a.b.c     a     b     c     a.b.c
aa.bb     aa    bb          aa.bb
x.z       x           z     x.z
.p.pp           p     pp    p.pp
!!!       !!!               !!!
.fff                  fff   fff
<----------- blank line ----------->
```

Comment: it is still wrong, if third value is null it gives you a _dot_ at the end